# Why does binary search algorithm require returning the recursive calls?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, return

I was implementing recursive binary search and I ran into this problem that really confused me. Here is the code that I was initially running:

'''

```
int recursiveBinarySearch(int* arr, int start, int end, int key){
   int middle = (start + end) / 2;

   if (start >= end)return -1;

   if (arr[middle] == key)return middle;

   if (arr[middle] < key) {
    recursiveBinarySearch(arr, middle+1, end, key);
   }

   if (arr[middle] > key) {
    recursiveBinarySearch(arr, start, middle-1, key);
   }

}
```

'''

Now, as far as I understand, as soon as a base case is reached, the only thing returned should be the value that is returned from the base-case because no other call is returning anything.
However, clearly I was wrong because this wasn't giving correct answers and apparently I needed a return statement infront of each of the recursive call for this algo to work, as I found out later.
So my question is, why do we need to have the **return** statement? What exactly is the reason that my solution doesn't work?

Comment: The function is declared to return a value. What value are you returning in the cases where you made a recursive call?

Comment: `recursiveBinarySearch()` = call function, throw away the result, `return recursiveBinarySearch()` = call function, use its result as our return value

Comment: Trace the flow on paper for the case where you search for 3 in 1,2,3, and you'll see why.

Comment: `int* arr` <-- this is wrong, especially in C++. it is a pointer to an int. Don't use it for arrays. Actually, use `std::array` or `std::vector` in C++ or an `std::span` in modern C++. But the C++ standard library would actually use iterators for this.

Comment: `int middle = (start + end) / 2;` is also wrong... what if `start+end` overflows?

Comment: See [Reason for return statement in recursive function call](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201765/reason-for-return-statement-in-recursive-function-call)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume, `X` is the function we are calling from the main function. And there is a function `Y` which is being called from function `X`. Function `Y` does some computation and calculates the result for `X`. So you should just call function `Y` and return it's result like below.

```
Y() {
 // Some computation
 return result;
}

X() {
 return Y();
}

main() {
  res = X();
}
```

Now think of it like this, each recursive call is a separate function that is doing some task. So your `recursiveBinarySearch` function should return the answer but it can't compute that itself, so it is calling some other functions (which in this case the same function, thus call recursion) to get the result. So it will keep calling the function and break down the problems into smaller ones until it reaches the base case where it will get the answer and finally return it.

Comment: The example you give is a bit odd, since the return value of `X()` is ignored by `main` anyway.

Comment: I just tried to make my point to help him understand recursion easily. I think he understood. But I am modifying it for future reference @Stef